# How can I convert all numbers in a string to hexadecimal using gsub?

Tags: ruby, hex, gsub

I'm trying to convert all numbers in a string to hex.
I tried this code:

```
str.gsub(/(\d+)/, '\1'.to_i.to_s(16))
```

But this replaces every number with `0` because it modifies the string `'\1'` instead of the number that replaces `\1`.

How can I do this correctly using `gsub`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) accepts a block. The return value of the block is used as the replacement value:

```
>> str = '100 200'
=> "100 200"
>> str.gsub(/\d+/) { |x| x.to_i.to_s(16) }
=> "64 c8"
```

Comment: It's not necessary to thank us for those type if changes. It's part of housekeeping for StackOverflow.